# How to get the image key of the selected item in listView

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listView object and also an imageList object and they are connected by image keys.

I want to select an item in the listView and get the image key of this item.
How to do this?

I tried something like this:

```
private void SongList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        //int index = this.SongList.SelectedItems[0];
        string key = this.SongList.SelectedItems[0].ImageKey;
}
```

But no success. It shows: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

Please help.

Comment: That means there are no selected Items at that time. You should check that there are selected items first.

Comment: How? I thought that this function will be called only if an item selected

Comment: Oh with count.. well i understood. Thank you!